# Error 'tuple' object has no attribute 'obs - Python GraphQL Strawberry + FastAPI

Tags: python, graphql, fastapi, strawberry-graphql

I'm starting a graphql project where I'm creating an API to get data from an Informix database.
I've managed to get everything working but I can't get any results and instead I get the error

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'obs
```

Any help would be appreciated!

This is what I have

[main.py]

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from schema import graphql_app 
app = FastAPI() 
app.include_router(graphql_app, prefix='/bitola')
```

[schema.py]

```
from typing import Optional, List
import strawberry
import datetime 
from strawberry.fastapi import GraphQLRouter 
from dbfunctions import get_bitola

@strawberry.type
class Bitola: 
    cod_bitola: Optional[int] 
    des_abr_bitola: str 
    des_bitola: str 
    qtd_largura: int 
    data_insercao: datetime.datetime 
    data_alteracao: datetime.datetime 
    obs: str

@strawberry.type
class Query: 
    allBitolas: List[Bitola] = strawberry.field(resolver=get_bitola)

schema = strawberry.Schema(query=Query)
graphql_app = GraphQLRouter(schema, graphiql=True, allow_queries_via_get=False)
```

[dbfunctions.py]

```
import jaydebeapi
def get_bitola():
    conn = jaydebeapi.connect("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver",
                            "jdbc:informix-sqli://ifxserver:INFORMIXSERVER=ifxdv",
                            ["user", "pass"],
                            "/path/to/jdbcdriver/informix-jdbc-complete-4.50.4.1.jar")
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute('select * from bitola')
    ldb = curs.fetchall()
    curs.close()
    conn.close()
    return ldb
```

When testing with

```
hypercorn main:app
```

i go to `localhost:8000/bitola` and input the query

```
{
  allBitolas {
    obs
  }
}
```

i get the error message

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "'tuple' object has no attribute 'obs'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "allBitolas",
        0,
        "obs"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and I can't understand why.

TY for all the help and pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lib i'm using (jaydebeapi), cursor.fetchAll() returns a list of tuples, whereas the resolver needs to return a list of instances of Bitola. So for each member in the list returned from the db call, I need to transform it into an instance.

So I did and it's working as intendend.

```
@dataclass
class Bitola2:
    cod_bitola: int
    des_abr_bitola: str
    des_bitola: str
    qtd_largura: int
    data_insercao: str
    data_alteracao: str
    obs: str

def TransformTuple(dbrec):
    return Bitola2(cod_bitola=dbrec[0], des_abr_bitola=dbrec[1], des_bitola=dbrec[2], qtd_largura=dbrec[3], data_insercao=dbrec[4], data_alteracao=dbrec[5], obs=dbrec[6])
```

Answered on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/graphql/comments/vra0l1/help_error_tuple_object_has_no_attribute_obs/)